# How to print out ≠ to terminal using g++?

Tags: c++, netbeans, g++, mingw, special-characters

I want to print `≠` in the terminal. I tried

```
cout << '\u2248' << endl;
cout << '\U00002248' << endl;
cout << '≠' << endl;
```

which gives

```
14846344
14846344
14846368
```

I tried replacing the single quotes with double

```
Ôëê
Ôëê
Ôëá
```

How can it be done? I'm curious what the explanation for the output I'm getting is? I'm running Netbeans 9 but have tested directly from command line with g++ too. I think this should be possible because `echo ≠` produces the correct output in the Windows command prompt.

Comment: Two things: First of all multi-character literals are an implementation specific thing. Use either wide-character literals or strings. Secondly, since you mention MinGW I guess you're on Windows, and the Windows console historically is very bad at Unicode (or really anything not in the currently selected code-page).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Use either wide-character literals or strings." is that what I did by putting them in double quotes? Also I tried adding `L` to the front and it's different output but still wrong.

Comment: try using UnicodeString or AnsiString type to declare strings. it might work

Comment: @EdinHajdarevic Those are Borland C++ / Embarcadero RAD Studio specific classes, and as such *very* non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in C++, like in plain C, by default we can work just with ASCII characters. 
***Char*** variables contains just 8 bits(1 byte) to store values so maximum - 2^8=256 different symbols can be coded by one char variable.
Single quotes (like 'a') are storing char variables so inside of them can be placed just ASCII-character. Your character is not a part of ASCII table and we need to change the encoding.

For just print(not store/process) your character, you should use another encoding such as UTF-8. You can do it programmatically:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, /*some system-specific locale name, probably */ "en_US.UTF-8");
std::cout << "\u2260" << std::endl;
```

Or via command line options to g++ (such as *-finput-charset=UTF-16*).
As you can see, I'm using double quotes to print non-ASCII symbols to console.

Comment: This didn't work. I think there's a bug/non-implemented feature where MinGW doesn't support changing locales.

Comment: Yes, @northerner, you are right.
For MinGW _std::setlocale_ is not realized. But instead of it, you can use _setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");_ - it's C-style function that can be used in C++ too.

Comment: In my case for MinGW this code is work fine:
`_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
std::wcout << L"\u2260" << std::endl;`
with including <io.h> and <fcntl.h>

Comment: I get the error `_fileno was not declared in this scope`

Comment: My main.cpp code: 
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
 _setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
 std::wcout << L"\u2260" << std::endl;
 return 0;
}`
command to compile it:
`g++ main.cpp -o example`
In my case, minGW was: g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0

Comment: Thanks that worked, I think I had forgotten to include right headers.